# mock function dependencies in other modules with jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I have a controller module which is dependent on a service module and calls it internally.
My module under test is the controller and I want to test it independently so I mock the service function that the controller is dependent on. But controller call s the original function instead of mocked one.

I have read the documentation and other questions and tied many approaches but none worked

Here is my latest try:

```
    const teacherDB = jest.genMockFromModule('./teacher-db')

    teacherDB.getCoursesOfTeacher = jest.fn(id => {
      logger.debug('MOCKED!')
      return 'FAKE'
    })
    const teacherController = require('./teacher-controller')
    const res = {}
    res.send = jest.fn()
    res.status = jest.fn(obj => res)
    //Here is where I call a function that is dependent on a teacherDB function (one that is mocked)
    // I mocked it but it calls the original instead of mocked version above
    await teacherController.getCoursesOfTeacher({
      params: {
        id: new Types.ObjectId()
      }
    }, res)

    expect(res.send).toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(res.send).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(expect.objectContaining({
      code: 2
    }))

  })
```

I expect to get code 2 (success, meaning that my function isn't dependent on my teacherDB, it calls the mocked version instead)
but I get code 4 (meaning that id doesn't exist which is right if I called the teacherDB)

Comment: `genMockFromModule` creates a mock from the module you specify, it does't swap it out when it's included in other modules. Is there a particular function of the module you want to mock?

Comment: @James yes, the one that I mocked , `getCoursesOfTeacher` form module `teacher-db`, because `teacherController.getCoursesOfTeacher` calls it internally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[genMockFromModule](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestgenmockfrommodulemodulename) isn't what you are looking for in this example, this just creates a mock from the module, it doesn't actually mock it globally - you want [jest.mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules)

```
const teacherDB = require('./teacher-db');
const teacherController = require('./teacher-controller');

// mock DB the module
jest.mock('./teacher-db');

test('test mock', async () => {
  teacherDB.getCoursesOfTeacher.mockResolvedValue('FAKE');

  const res = {
    send: jest.fn(),
    status: jest.fn(() => res)
  };

  await teacherController.getCoursesOfTeacher({
    params: {
      id: new Types.ObjectId()
    }
  }, res);

  expect(res.send).toHaveBeenCalled()
  expect(res.send).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(expect.objectContaining({
    code: 2
  }));
});
```

Comment: thanks, it worked (after changing `jest.mock(teacherDB);` to `jest.mock('./teacher-db');` ) ,  but how can I implement the mock function manually?

Comment: @Apptic whoops my bad, updated. Depends what you mean by that? This _is_ an example of mocking the function.

Comment: yes now I get it, I just wanted to know what if we don't want to use `mockResolvedValue` and want to write the mock function implementation, until I read the function's documentation:`(value: jest.ResolvedValue<T>): this

Simple sugar function for: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(value));` thank you

Comment: Cool. I didn't know that `mockResolvedValue` is just an alias / syntactic sugar: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockresolvedvaluevalue

Answer (score 0):

fixed it by adding the service module to exports of the controller module, then mocking it:

```
const teacherController = require('./teacher-controller')
teacherController.teacherDB.getCoursesOfTeacher = jest.fn(id => {
  return 'FAKE'
})
```

it worked but I'm not sure if there is a better way so I won't pick my answer as the best answer.

Comment: This would work, however, you need to be careful to restore the mock back. What you want to do can be done, see my answer.